# Get selected values from all dropdowns except one that is triggering event

Tags: jquery

I want to check if there are any other selected values which match the current selection. So when `.payment-method` changes I get the value and check the other `.payment-method`s for their values. I want to exclude the drop down which triggered the change. `.not(this)` is not working.

```
$(document).on('change', '.payment-method', function() {
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    console.log("this value" + thisVal);

    $(".payment-method option:selected").not(this).each(function () {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're using `not()` against the `option` elements with `this`, which references a `select`, hence it's always false. To fix this, call `not()` on a selector containing the `.payment-method` elements and then use `find()` to get the selected options, like this:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.payment-method', function() {
  $('.payment-method').not(this).find('option:selected').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="payment-method">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
  <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="payment-method">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
  <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
</select>
<select class="payment-method">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
  <option value="fizz">Fizz</option>
  <option value="buzz">Buzz</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for dupe values, you can filter it, e.g:

```
$(document).on('change', '.payment-method', function() {

  var thisVal = $(this).val();
  console.log("this value" + thisVal);

  var anyDupeVal = !!$(".payment-method").not(this).filter(function() {
    return this.value === thisVal
  }).length;

  console.log(anyDupeVal); // true or false

});
```

And if you want all other values as your title suggests it, then you could map it to get an array of values:

```
var otherValues = $(".payment-method").not(this).map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
```

But imho, it isn't really clear what you are expecting as result.